# Parcel data duplicates

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I'm trying to populate a table with parcel information and assign sequential numbers while dealing with some parcels that have anywhere between 2-50+ entries.  One owner has many parcels.  Is there a way to query out just duplicates to identify them.

Comment: Spatial duplicates, feature on top of feature?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: if you want to add a field and query the new field try the identify duplicate query:

uniqueList = []
def isDuplicate(inValue):
  if inValue in uniqueList:
    return 1
  else:
    uniqueList.append(inValue)
    return 0

Comment: if you want to add a field and query the new field try the identify duplicate query. you can access more background on this using the [ESRI Technical Article 38700](http://support.esri.com/em/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/38700)

Comment: To what are you assigning sequential numbers - parcels, owners, unique owner/parcel combinations, or all records? Based on your question wording, you have a many-to-many relationship (one parcel can have many owners, one owner can have many parcels). It depends on what you're trying to do as to how to solve the problem (and if you care about spatial duplicates, as artwork21 mentions).

Answer (score 1):

I've had this exact problem with BUP (Building Unit Plans) where title for each unit in an apartment block was stacked neatly on top of each other.

If you use the [feature to point tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003m000000) to create the centroids it will dutifully create one centroid per polygon. From this you can [collect events](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005p0000003s000000) for exact duplicates, but if they are not exact you will not find them. I planarized the polygons by using [feature to line](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000039000000) then [integrate](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000002s000000) to snap the boundaries together and [feature to polygon](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Feature_To_Polygon/00170000003n000000/) - this creates one polygon only for each group of boundaries that should be identical. Then using [intersect](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000p000000) and [summary statistics](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Summary_Statistics/00080000001z000000/) with a count of the polygon id I could recognize duplicate centroids.